# php remove output buffering

Tags: php, output-buffering

I am doing a lot of processing at my PHP page and I want to display progress information to the user, for instance, finished 10% 20% and so. What is happening now is that all the data is displayed at once after processing is done, how can I display it right away!

I tried to set comment out output buffer in `php.ini` and I tried to use `flush()` after `echo` statements, not working, any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
ob_start();
while ($line = read_file_line("c:/1.txt")) {  
  $read_lines_count++;
  if($read_lines_count % 100 == 0) {
    echo "parsed $read_lines_count <br />";
  ob_flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: This depends on the server configurtion as well. If you want to be sure, split the job in parts and use ajax. If ajax is an option of course.

Comment: @xd6_ I just tried it, nop :( still waits until processing is done...

Comment: @jeroen, I have access to the server, any changes I need to make in php.ini ?

Comment: @AminM I'm not sure, there is a lot more than just php involved.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to call `ob_start()` before any code is printed.

Then echo whatever you want

call `ob_flush()` when you want to show the buffer on screen.

and at the end, a call to `ob_end_flush()` to end buffering and show output.

Make sure your php.ini has this line **uncommented**:

```
output_buffering = On
```

More Info : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: @AminM you need to explicitly set `output_buffering` to true in the php.ini, commenting the line will set it to false (default's apache value). Do a `var_dump(ini_get('output_buffering'))` and it will show you the output_buffering configuration

Comment: I just did it's
string '4096' (length=4)

Comment: @AminM This means that it will buffer up to 4086 bytes at most. Write in your php.ini `output_buffering = On` http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering

Comment: yeah sorry! I meant to say I set it to on, vardump is string: 1
 :(

Comment: @AminM Are you sure the file is long enough ? It might be instant if you try on your localhost or may be fast if the file is less than 1Mb on a remote host and can't even notice it's buffering.

Comment: the page takes 300 seconds of processing, but all data is displayed after it's done, I wanted it to display progress during the processing.

Notice output size is small though, less than 20 lines.